# Show password icon

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML...

```
<div class="signin-form-label-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Password"
               required>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <span toggle="#password" class="mdi mdi-eye-off toggle-password"></span>
      </div>
```

And this jQuery:

```
$(".toggle-password").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("mdi mdi-eye");
      var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
      input.type === "password" ? input.type = "text" : input.type = "password";
    });
```

I am using material design icons. Problem is that when clicking the eye-off icon, the text is displayed but the icon does not change to eye only. Any way to fix it?

EDIT: I found that the problem actually is...
By default the class has `class="mdi-eye-off toggle-password mdi"`. When clicking on the eye-off, this happens...
`class="mdi-eye-off toggle-password mdi-eye"`
Surely the mdi-eye-off should have been removed due to the toggle class. But is hasn't. Why? How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Like this to show password HTML

```
<div class="signin-form-label-group">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control"
           placeholder="Password"
           required>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <span toggle="#password" class="mdi mdi-eye-off toggle-password" onclick="myFunction(this)">Eye</span>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction(e) {

      var x = document.getElementById("password");
      if (x.type === "password") {
          e.classList.add('mdi-eye')
        e.classList.remove('mdi-eye-off')
        x.type = "text";
      } else {
          e.classList.add('mdi-eye-off')
        e.classList.remove('mdi-eye')
        x.type = "password";
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery.

```
$(".toggle-password").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("your-toggle-class");
    var input = $("#password");
    if (input.attr("type") === "password") {
        input.attr("type", "text");
    } else {
        input.attr("type", "password");
    }

});
```